# Short way to query Dataset by the value of several columns

Tags: dataset, associations

I learned how to query `Dataset` for rows that contain a certain value, but now I need to query for a long series of `And` in chain on the value of several columns. So in short I am trying to identify the row where x={x1, ..., xn} takes a certain value.

For a Dataset like this

```
  ds = Dataset[{Association[{"x1" -> myX, "x2" -> myX, "x3" -> myX, 
  "x4" -> myX, "y" -> myY}], 
Association[{"x1" -> myotherX, "x2" -> myotherX, "x3" -> myX, 
  "x4" -> myX, "y" -> myotherY}]}];
```

I can do

```
   ds[Select[(#x1 == myotherX && #x2 == myotherX && #x3 == myX && #x4 == 
  myX) &], "y"]
```

but the expression is long to type and less and less convenient as from 2 argument I go to a larger numbers.

*Ideally* I wanted to able to call something like

```
  ReadRow[ds,<|"x1"->myX,"x2"->myX,"x3"->myX,"x4"->myX|>,"y"]
```

Any idea how to do this? something like this should be a standard way to deal with Dataset.

---

My best result so far is to  "translate" the `Association` into a check for the value I am looking for and put all the entered keys of the association

```
  RuleToEquality[a_, b_] := Slot[a] == b
  MgPyResults[
        Select[(KeyValueMap[RuleToEquality, <|x1 -> myX|>][[1]]) &], "y"]
```

This, however, does not match the entries, despite the

```
InputForm[
     Tr[KeyValueMap[RuleToEquality, <|x1 -> myX, x2 -> myX|>], And]]
```

gives the correct

```
 Slot[x1] == myX && Slot[x2] == myX
```

Comment: Your verbal description and you code examples don't seem consistent to me. Further, a data set with only one row doesn't make for a good example. I am voting to close this question as unclear.

Comment: One row is more than enough to retrieve one row. Why should I put on the code more entries than needed? anyways, I am editing the question, maybe is only my point of view.

Comment: @RobertoFranceschini, "Why should I put on the code more entries than needed?" non-matching entries are typically needed to test potential false positives.

Comment: In your `ReadRow[ds,<|x1->myX,x2->myX,x3->myX,x4->myX|>,"y"]` the `Keys` in your example are strings so `x1`... should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: correct(ed), thanks for "compiling" my question :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have your $\{column, value\}$ pairs in a list

```
findList = {{"x1", myX}, {"x2", myX}, {"x3", myX}, {"x4", myX}};
```

then you can build the `Select` criteria function from it.

```
selectCriteria[find_List] :=
 And @@ Function[{item}, #[item[[1]]] == item[[2]]] /@ find &
```

`selectCriteria` builds up the `Equal` pairs and chains them with `And`.  It returns a function that can be used with `Select`.

```
ds[Select[selectCriteria[findList]], "y"]
(* {myY} *)
```

If your pairs are in an `Association` then convert it to a `List` before calling `selectCriteria`.

```
findAssc = <|"x1" -> myX, "x2" -> myX, "x3" -> myX, "x4" -> myX|>;

ds[Select[selectCriteria[List @@@ Normal@findAssc]], "y"]
(* {myY} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this will be of use to you:

```
ds = Dataset[{
     <|"x1" -> myX, "x2" -> myX, "x3" -> myX, "x4" -> myX, "y" -> myY|>,
     <| "x1" -> myotherX, "x2" -> myotherX, "x3" -> myX, "x4" -> myX, "y" -> myotherY|>
   }];

sel = <|"x1" -> myX, "x2" -> myX, "x3" -> myX, "x4" -> myX|>;

sel2 = <|"x1" -> myotherX, "x2" -> myotherX, "x3" -> myX, "x4" -> myX|>;

pull[sel_] := Select[sel == KeyTake[#, Keys@sel] &];

ds[pull @ sel, "y"]
ds[pull @ sel2, "y"]
```

> ```
> {myY}
>
> {myotherY}
> ```